# What happens to the TCP congestion window when packet loss occurs at slow start stage?

Tags: tcp

In TCP, packet loss can be detected in two ways: timeout and three ACKs (for one certain packet, ie. the loss packet).

Assume that timeout has not been reached yet, what happens to the congestion window if a packet loss happens during the slow start stage? Will the congestion window still increase by 1 when receiving the first duplicated ACK?

For example, at the view of the sender, initially the window size is 3:
[1 2 3]

Packet 1 and its ACK (the ACK for packet 1) are sent and received. Therefore the window size increases by 1, ie. to 4:
[2 3 4 5]

Packet 2 is sent but it's lost. Then when packet 3 is sent successfully, a duplicated ACK (still for packet 1) arrives, what is the window size at this point?

1) If the window size could increase due to receiving of this first duplicated ACK (note that the sender doesn't know packet loss now because there is only one duplicated ACK and timeout has not been reached yet), it should be:
[2 3 4 5 6]

2) Otherwise, perhaps because ACK for packet 1 has been received already (because packet 1 is sent successfully), the window size may remain 4:
[2 3 4 5]

Which one is true for TCP?

Many thanks!

Comment: @EJP Sorry I mean the ACK waiting for new incoming packet 2. I've edited the description for this ambiguity.

Comment: @EJP And, the ACK number is the highest sequence number that is received **+1**. That is what I want to say.

Comment: It is acknowledging all the data received up to and excluding the sequence number. Describing it as an ACK for an unreceived packet doesn't make sense, and neither does 'ACK waiting for packet 2'. Just remove the confusion.

Comment: @EJP Yes you are right - for the first version. Therefore I have edited it. It acknowledges all packets before packet 1 (included), or just packet 1 (because there is no previous packet), or waiting for packet 2.

Comment: If you would only *stop* saying 'waiting for packet 2' your question and comments would make sense. Try to kick the habit.

Comment: @EJP  Sure no problem. I have removed the confusing statements. Hope that makes more sense. If so, do you have any opinion into this?

Comment: Well I don't see any reason why the congestion window should change while congestion is still evident, but it's still off-topic.

Comment: @EJP  ok.. I have thought receiving any ACK (even duplicated ones) would increase the window size as well and that's what I want to ask. Thanks for sharing the insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this might be off topic at StackOverflow, I still believe this is an important and interesting issue. I post the answer I find here:

A similar (actually almost the same) question:
[Does TCP increase its congestion window when Dup Acks arrive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32954156/does-tcp-increase-its-congestion-window-when-dup-acks-arrive?rq=1)

Answer:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5681#section-3.2

In more detail:

> On the first and second duplicate ACKs received at a sender ... the
> TCP sender MUST NOT change cwnd to reflect these two segments

> For each additional duplicate ACK received (after the third),
> cwnd MUST be incremented by SMSS.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly , window size is set depending on the flow control .
Generally it is 4096 bytes or 8192 bytes and it may change.

So your window size does not depend on the congestion parameters or lost packets.

Now at the very beginning , one packet is sent ( 1 MSS size packet ). If ack for the first packet is received successfully , then it will increase the rate of packets being sent . It will double the size for every acknowledgement. So the congestion window grows exponentially. At certain point , due to congestion it figures out the loss due to timeout or duplicate ACK received. If it receives duplicate ACk , then it will half the congestion windows size and then increases the congwin by adding 1. It increases linearly. If loss is due to timeout then , it will set conwin to 1 and does perform  slow start algorithm . In case duplicate ack received it runs fast recovery algorithm .

Slow start stage is where the rate at which packets are sent into transmission like grows exponentially, and after figuring out congestion due to loss event , it half's the congestion window value and increased linearly . Now it will be in congestion avoidance stage.